# Replacing a stylesheet in a complex header

Tags: jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I have a website that I need to create a stylesheet switcher for. Now I am pretty much self taught when it comes to all things html/css/js so please forgive my newbness in advance. I modified some code to suit my needs but I can't seem to find how to change the code to target a specific line in the head.

Currently this is what I have:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#" rel="http://files.enjin.com/149304/theme-dark.css">Dark</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="http://files.enjin.com/149304/theme-light.css">Light</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#nav li a").click(function() { 
        $("link").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    if($.cookie("css")) {
        $("link").attr("href",$.cookie("css"));
    }
    $("#nav li a").click(function() { 
        $("link").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));
        $.cookie("css",$(this).attr('rel'), {expires: 365, path: '/'});
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    if($.cookie("css")) {
        $("link").attr("href",$.cookie("css"));
    }
    $("#nav li a").click(function() { 
        $("link").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));
        $.cookie("css",$(this).attr('rel'), {expires: 365, path: '/'});
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

As it stands at the moment this code just changes every href in the head and destroys the page.

This is the href I need to change (it lives on line 22):

```
<link href="./Home - Oceanian Gaming Community_files/theme.php" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can put all those in one ready handler.. That would be cleaner. Plus it'll help you catch errors sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot traverse DOM element by their line number in source code.

You need to differentiate the link tag you need altered using some technique. A simple suggestion is to use a custom attribute.

For ex:

```
<link xtype="1" href="./Home - Oceanian Gaming Community_files/theme.php"  ... >
```

Now, you can refer that via a selector and manipulate it easily.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#nav li a").click(function() { 
        $("link[xtype="1"]").attr("href", $(this).attr('rel'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

The above is the only ready handler you'll need for the purpose.

---

A slightly riskier solution would be to use the attribute-contains selector to match the specific link tag. The risk is that this may match multiple link tags depending on what you have on your page.

```
$("link[href*="/theme.php"]")
```

---

**Edit** after reviewing the site:

Ok, so a couple of things were incorrect.

Firstly, the quotes were wrong - You need $('link[href*="/theme.php"]') i.e. single outside, double inside for the pattern (or vice-versa, but not the same one in both places).

Secondly, after you change it once, the pattern href*="/theme.php" wont match again since we've changed the href attribute. So add a custom attribute the first time you change the `href` and using this custom attribute to match your link tag from second time on wards.

```
if($('link[xtype]').length == 0) {
    // first time - set href and add custom attribute
    $('link[href*="/theme.php"]').attr("href", $(this).attr('rel')).attr('xtype', 1);
}
else {
    // second time on wards
    $('link[xtype]').attr("href", $(this).attr('rel')).attr('xtype', 1);
}
```

Comment: There is one possible solution though it could be risky if there is a possibility of there being more than one link tag with similar a href attribute. See the edit.

Comment: getting the link element using jQuery('link').eq(number) helps?

Comment: @Kuro - Try reducing the match pattern to just "theme.php" instead of the complete URL. i.e. `$("link[href*="theme.php"]")` - That should do the trick.

Comment: Do you have the page up in a URL or a fiddle perhaps. I can look into it.

Comment: @techfoobar - I most certainly do. I placed the style switcher at the top of the right hand column.  http://www.oceanian.com.au/hometestpagestackoverflow

Comment: Ok, so a couple of things were incorrect. Firstly, the quotes were wrong - You need `$('link[href*="/theme.php"]')` i.e. single outside, double inside for the pattern (or vice-versa, but not the same one in both places).

Comment: Secondly, after you change it once, the pattern `href*="/theme.php"` wont match again since we've changed the href attribute. So add a custom attribute the first time you change the href and using this custom attribute to match your link tag from second time onwards. I think its better if i put in an edit.

Comment: BTW, your theme-Dark.css is not accessible.

Comment: @techfoobar - I updated the code (its on the page I linked), but it doesn't work. The dark theme should work now as well - http://files.enjin.com/149304/theme-dark.css

Comment: Thats because the `rel` attribute in your `<a>` tag has `theme-Dark.css` instead of `theme-dark.css`. Changing it to `http://files.enjin.com/149304/theme-dark.css` solves the issue. Your hosting server seems to be running an OS with a case-sensitive file system.

Comment: @techfoobar - any idea why it's replacing the link but not loading it?